# Install obr plugin in Nexus

Tags: osgi, nexus, obr

I would like to install the Nexus-obr-plugin [GitHub](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-oss/tree/master/plugins/osgi/nexus-obr-plugin) in my Nexus oss 2.10.0-02.

The OBR-plugin seems not to be shipped in the Standard Nexus OSS. I could find the jar Version of this plugin http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonatype.nexus.plugins/nexus-obr-plugin/2.10.0-02.

I looked at the other Plugins shipped with Nexus, every plugin seems to be in a folder containing the jar,Manifestfile (under META-INF) and required dependencies.

I placed the jar in the folder `plugin-repository/nexus-obr-plugin-2.10.0-02/nexus-obr-plugin-2.10.0-02.jar`. Downloaded required dependecies in the dependencies folder:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.osgi.service.obr</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and created a MANIFEST File, based on other MANIFEST Files from other Nexus Plugins. With this I managed to start Nexus without Errors and the Plugin Console states that the OBR-Plugin is Activated. But there is no OBR Provider available  under 'Create new Hosted repository'.

Is there a good explanation how to install the obr plugin and where can the plugin with all dependencies and MANIFEST File be downloaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the bundle folder rather than just the jar file. These can be downloaded in zip format from the sonatype repository:

`https://repository.sonatype.org`

For the 2.10.0-02 OBR bundle you'll find it here:

`https://repository.sonatype.org/service/local/repo_groups/forge/content/org/sonatype/nexus/plugins/nexus-obr-plugin/2.10.0-02/nexus-obr-plugin-2.10.0-02-bundle.zip`

unzip that to the `plugin-repository` folder and restart nexus.

Comment: I have updated the documentation around this in the Nexus book now as well. http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/osgi-sect-intro.html